# Is an "elevator pitch" called "lift pitch" in the UK?

Tags: british-english

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch

No mention of "lift pitch" there. What do British people say when they give an "elevator pitch"? Since "elevator" is "lift" in the UK, you'd think it would be "lift pitch", but maybe there's a completely different phrase used there?

Comment: We say "lift" in Australia, but I have never heard anyone say "lift pitch". I have (occasionally) heard the term "elevator pitch".

Comment: Just a *pitch*.

Comment: If I was on an elevator and it pitched I'd hit the emergency stop!

Comment: Interesting thought. Probably because it was coined in the US, and we have no need for an alternative 'translation'.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard it called anything but an "elevator pitch", because it's a specifically American concept.

In Britain, no-one talks to anyone else in a lift, let alone tries to sell them something! The most that will ever be said is "Ooh. Air conditioning. Lovely", or some similar phrase about the weather. The concept of a "lift pitch" is entirely alien.

The nearest you're likely to find is something like ***potted description*** or ***short introduction.*** The term "pitch" (just "pitch") might be used; it's become more common in British English, although OED has it as "originally slang" and the earliest citation is from 1876.

Comment: In the U.S., it's very rare that strangers talk to you in an elevator, and I don't think they would ever try to sell you something.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear it. I realise the name is derived from the average length of time an elevator journey takes, but that's simply another reason the phrase is lifted wholesale into BrE, or replaced altogether. It doesn't need to be "translated".

Comment: +1. This may be the most perfectly British answer I've ever read on EL&U.

Comment: The origins aren't in pitching to a stranger, though...the idea is that you're pitching it to a manager or executive in the list whose ear you wouldn't normally have.

Comment: My answer doesn't mention strangers at all. And "selling something" could just as easily be persuading of a concept: perhaps I'm guilty of a transatlanticism.

Comment: To continue with U.S. elevator etiquette, if you're with a group of people and you walk into an empty elevator, you generally continue your conversation. If you get into an elevator that is already occupied, you often stop talking while you're in the elevator. I can't imagine that the etiquette is that different in the U.K.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase used is still "elevator pitch".  It is just a business jargon phrase that doesn't get translated like "in the ball park".

The whole concept though is rather strange, because the last thing you would do in Britain is talk to a stranger in a lift.

Comment: The origins aren't in pitching to a stranger, though...the idea is that you're pitching it to a manager or executive in the list whose ear you wouldn't normally have.

Comment: @calum_b - I've always heard it in the context of selling, how do you say enough about what your business does in 30 seconds to catch their attention.  It does make more sense if you are pitching an idea to someone you know but don't normally have much direct contact with.

Answer (score 2):

I understand "elevator pitch" to be a short expression of a viewpoint or opinion that lasts no longer than a typical elevator ride - about a minute or thereabouts. The speaker makes a "pitch" for the opinion in the time defined by the elevator occupancy. (American)

In Britain we refer to an elevator as a lift; we refer to a pitch in the same way as in America ("make your pitch" = "Give us your viewpoint") but I have never heard the term "lift pitch" in colloquial, business or other use. I think it would not be understood here.